# How to collect not one dependency error at a time, but all dependency errors at once?

Tags: java, maven

I am building a project using Maven. However, if any dependency is missing I get an error saying that some 1 dependency is missing. If I download the missing dependency and build it again then a new error may appear saying that 1 more dependency is missing.

How can I make it so that when building it immediately tells me every dependency which is missing rather than just 1? I'm on Linux, so plugins won't work. You can display the dependency tree `mvn dependency:tree`, but this didn’t really help me either. It crashed in the middle of the build. The task is to find out whether there is a way to identify all the necessary dependencies if it is not possible to load them. So that we can provide a list of what is missing, rather than constantly adding to the list.

I also tried the `-fae` flag, but it didn’t help.

Comment: likely 'not'. Besides, how would that check know what solution you would introduce, and how many of the issues would be resolved by it? It's pretty hard to flag an error that hasn't been encountered yet

Comment: I dont think you can as it tries to compile-build the project, and only when it hits the issue, will it inform you that there is a missing dependency.

Comment: What do you mean "plugins won't work?" Maven plugins are, of course, cross platform.

Comment: But you can’t make it so that if there is an error in one dependency, it will also generate an error about another error. That is, it will not stop at one dependency error, but will continue to collect, and if there is another dependency error, it will also issue a second one

Comment: What does this means: `I download a new dependency,` The dependencies you have defined in your pom file will be automatically downloaded... ?

Comment: A good IDE should tell you.  Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely not possible.

But generally not a big problem. You need to download the dependencies from MavenCentral or from a Nexus/Artifactory in your company that proxies MavenCentral.

Be warned: You CANNOT download all the dependencies manually because "the server is not connected to the internet" or something like that.

Comment: How can I immediately understand the list of dependencies that I am missing? So that after loading a new dependency, you don’t have to reassemble the project and crash on another dependency

Comment: @Vanish I think you can't. But why are you missing so many dependencies? They should be available on MavenCentral or your Nexus/Artifactory.